# How should I patch fonts for use with the vim plugin Powerline?

Tags: vim

My operating system is Windows 8.1 64 bit, I have installed `fontforge` and  `fontpatcher`, but I don't know how to use it to patch fonts. Could you give me a usage demo,thank you very much! [This is the web site for powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/master/)
but I can't find usage. [This is fontpatcher's project home on github](https://github.com/powerline/fontpatcher)

I have tried to use the `python powerline-fontpatcher` command to look for help, but failed.

Comment: What do you  mean by "failed"? What did you try? What did you expect? What happened instead? I notice that there is a link on fontpatcher's GitHub page to https://github.com/powerline/fonts which provides "pre-patched and adjusted fonts". As they are provided in *.ttf format you may be able to use them directly an Windows 8.

Comment: i'm sorry,I am not familiar with English.i'm can not use word exactly.my real mean is how to patch  my custom font,i need the method or the process not the result.

Answer (score 0):

### Steps

- follow the windows installation instructions [here](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Installing_Fontforge.html)
- `git clone` [this repo](https://github.com/alexandermckay/font-patcher)
- Copy the font file you would like to patch into the downloaded repo
- `cd <repo location>`
- `fontforge -script font-patcher <path to font>`
- Wait for the script to finish and then open the newly created font file, install it
- Restart your terminal and select the newly created font in preferences